# Write at certain byte/position in file Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there any equivalent to `seekp()` in OCaml ?
I need to write chars in a file at certain offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An utop example, to write a character ('A') at a certain position inside a file (Test.data):

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "unix";;
open Unix;;

let fd=openfile "Test.data" [O_WRONLY; O_TRUNC; O_CREAT] 0o666;;

let nbBytes=lseek fd 12 Unix.SEEK_SET;;      
if nbBytes<>12 then failwith "Unix.lseek";;

let nbChars= write fd "A" 0 1;;     
if nbChars<>1 then failwith "Unix.write";;
close fd;;
```

od -cv Test.data

```
0000000  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   A
```

Explanations:

- SEEK_SET indicates positions relative to the beginning of the file.
- The result of lseek is offset from the **beginning** of the file.
- To rewind the file you can use : `lseek fd 0 Unix.SEEK_SET`.
- To read the **second** character of the file,  you have to do ( before reading):`lseek fd 1 Unix.SEEK_SET`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are looking for `Unix.lseek`, though I am unfamiliar with the exact semantics.